# User can not see reply message in chat app using signalr + angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have chat application and in that backend is done by asp.net core and front end is in angular.

Everything is working fine, just problem is as per below :

Let's say User A send message to User B so User B see that message instantly.

But when User B reply back to User A then User A can not see message instantly, But if User A refresh page OR click on any other username and click back on User B then he can see that reply message of User B.

So any one can guide me what can be problem for this.

```
if (window['chatHub'].connectionState == "Connected") {
//      alert("wwww");
      this._userService.sendMessage(this.input)
        .subscribe(resp => {
          console.log(resp);
          this.updateProfilePic(resp);
          this.Messages.push(resp);
          window['chatHub'].invoke('sendMessage', resp);

          this.scrollToBottom();
          this._formGroup.reset();
        });
    } else {
      //this.message.info("Connection was lost! Please send message again", "Connection lost");
      window['chatHub'].start();
    }
```

Comment: *If you want I can share source code here.* We *expect* you to share relevant code!

Comment: this looks like a tough one, sharing all the code may make us hard to diagnose, extracting just the most relevant code may not be easy for you (meaning no relevant code can be shared). So we're all stuck.

Comment: It seems that javascript does not render the page in real time, you can share the code  which renders page.

Comment: @Karney. In console log I am getting this error : zone.js:690 Unhandled Promise rejection: PushError: permission request declined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: PushError: permission request declined undefined

Comment: This error prompts asynchronous exception, but I can not reproduce it.

Comment: @Karney. 

his is ts file which is send message.

if (window['chatHub'].connectionState == "Connected") {
      this._userService.sendMessage(this.input)
        .subscribe(resp => {
          this.updateProfilePic(resp);
          this.Messages.push(resp);
          window['chatHub'].invoke('sendMessage', resp);

          this.scrollToBottom();
          this._formGroup.reset();
        });
    } else {
      //this.message.info("Connection was lost! Please send message again", "Connection lost");
      window['chatHub'].start();
    }