# Chatwindow does not update reply message from other user using signalr + angular + .net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have chat application and in that backend is done by asp.net core and front end is in angular, I am using signalr.

Everything is working fine, just problem is as per below :

Let's say User A send message to User B so User B see that message instantly.

But when User B reply back to User A then User A can not see message instantly, But if User A refresh page OR click on any other username and click back on User B then he can see that reply message of User B.

So any one can guide me what can be problem for this.

Below is ts file code which is responsible to send message.

```
if (window['chatHub'].connectionState == "Connected") {
//      alert("wwww");
      this._userService.sendMessage(this.input)
        .subscribe(resp => {
          console.log(resp);
          this.updateProfilePic(resp);
          this.Messages.push(resp);
          window['chatHub'].invoke('sendMessage', resp);

          this.scrollToBottom();
          this._formGroup.reset();
        });
    } else {
      //this.message.info("Connection was lost! Please send message again", "Connection lost");
      window['chatHub'].start();
    }
```

Comment: Did you intend to repost this? [User can not see reply message in chat app using signalr + angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65510113/user-can-not-see-reply-message-in-chat-app-using-signalr-angular)

Comment: Yes..I have posted with some source code.

Comment: Why didn't you just add the code to the other post via an edit? This is the same question otherwise.

Comment: ok..I have edited that question.

Comment: Feel free to delete this one when you can. Thank you!!